# How can i kill all the processes with same name and save one with same name but using exact PID?

Tags: batch-file

How can i kill all the processes with name "OPCExplorer.exe" except the one process with name "OPCExplorer.exe" but for example with PID = "8888"  ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the filters of the [tasklist](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) command:

```
@echo off


for /f "skip=3 tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq OPCExplorer.exe" /fi "PID ne 8888"') do (
  taskkill /pid %%a /f
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in `WMIC.exe`

```dos
WMIC Process Where "Name='OPCExplorer.exe' And Not ProcessId='8888'" Call Terminate
```